# UnionBy Linq Implementation

Tags: c#, linq

I needed an implementation on Union that compares a property of an object, rather the objects themselves. I came up with the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> UnionBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
    IEnumerable<TSource> second,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer = null)
{
    HashSet<TKey> keys = new HashSet<TKey>(keyComparer);
    foreach (TSource element in first)
    {
        if (keys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
    foreach (TSource element in second)
    {
        if (!keys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            continue;
        }
        yield return element;
    }
}
```

which I can use by saying something along the lines of:

```
result = first.UnionBy(second, x => x.Property1);
```

Which works for me, but I was wondering if there wasn't something already implemented in Linq that I was missing (**other than implementing my own EqualityComparer** which to me seems less intuitive).

Since I won't be using the same properties every time I want this union I would either have to make multiple `EqualityComparer`'s for each situation which doesn't seem correct to me, or make some generic `EqualityComparer` that would take in a property selector Func. It seemed less intuitive to me than just providing a generic Linq extension that accepted the property selector itself.

Comment: `Union` has an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407.aspx) with a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` or just implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your class.

Comment: @TimSchmelter "other than implementing my own `EqualityComparer` which to me seems less intuitive." I updated the question with an explanation as to why I chose not to do that. Basically it seemed counter-intuitive to me to create separate `EqualityComparer`'s or to override the `Equals` without the intention of utilizing them outside the Union.

Comment: There's no such method already implemented, and you listet already three possible solutions yourself. I prefer the generic `EqualityComparer`, since you have to implement it once and can use it for many methods (like `Union`, `Distinct`, `Except` etc. etc.)

Comment: in .NET #6 the LINQ methods like `UnionBy` will be (at last) natively available. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27687

Comment: @NominSim: Actually your code is doing Concat + DistinctBy. It would be conceptually better to implement just DistinctBy and feed it with `first.Concat(second)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can write it as follows instead:

```
var q = first.Concat(second).GroupBy(x => x.Property1).Select(x => x.First());
```

Comment: This looks good, and was just what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[UnionBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.unionby?view=net-7.0) is implemented in .NET 7 now

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with .NET 6+ [Enumerable.UnionBy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.unionby?view=net-6.0) with the exact syntax you specified. Just **pass a lambda containing your comparer property as the second parameter** of the `UnionBy()` method:

```
var result = first.UnionBy(second, x => x.Property1);
```

Don't forget to add

```
using System.Linq;
```